# How to select distinct values from a column with a newly created key as reference

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, window-functions

I am creating a distinct key by concatenating two different columns of a table.
Now the key which I have created can be repeated, for example column A is roll number of student and
column B is the optional subject in which he is enrolled. Now a student can be enrolled in multiple subjects as well as single optional subject, I want only those students roll number who are enrolled in only single optional subjects.

with the logic I am using I am getting the following error,

> Message:ERROR: window functions not allowed in WHERE clause

Please help

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(roll_number, subject) as key,
    count (key) over(partition by key) as values
FROM
    subject_data
WHERE
    roll_number is not null and subject is not null
    and values = 1
```

when I am using HAVING clause it is still throwing same error

Comment: Which are you using, MySQL or Oracle? Please don't spam unrelated tags.

Comment: Use `HAVING values = 1`. You can't refer to column aliases in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple CTE, to get your result

```
WITH CTE as
(SELECT CONCAT(roll_number, subject) as key1 FROM subject_data 
WHERE roll_number is not null and subject is not NULL), CTE2 AS
(SELECT key1, count(key1) over(partition by key1) as val FROM CTE)
SELECT  key1, val FROM CTE2
WHERE val = 1
```